# How to allow multiple form submits, as javascript handles the call.

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have set up a javascript form and I thought that it was going to allow me to continuously change the data in the form (without reloading) and then continuously re-submit, running the same javascript.

The structure of the form works as it runs through the javascript the first time, but now after that submission.

Here's the snipped structure:

```
<form name="items">
... form inputs... 
<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button2" Value="Update Cart" onClick="total(this.form)">
```

This runs a javascript function, which works.  Is this type of form set up not what I should do?

Comment: You mean every time anything in anyone of your input field changes you want to send a post request using Javascript?

Comment: use ajax to send a request every time you want to post

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't submit the form, its for homework, it just displays the data back on the page

Answer (score 1):

if you want to post the form multiple times without reloading the page - you are going to need to use ajax to post the form, or jquery's $.post() if you are using jquery.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify, its actually supposed to just display the data on the same page, not to any database or email.  Just take the data and show it.

Comment: so just to be clear - all you want is that when someone enters something in a field, you want to recalculate results and update the value in another field?